# Binding events emitted from member functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

js and EventEmitters. I have the following code below. I wanted to know how I could bind the "time" event on call of "getTime()" function.
Something like this :

```
timer.getTime.on("time", function() {
    console.log(new Date());
});
```

--Code--

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

    function Clock() {
        var self = this;
        this.getTime = function() {
            console.log("In getTime()");
            setInterval(function() {
                self.emit('time');
                console.log("Event Emitted!!");
            }, 1000);
        };
    }

    Clock.prototype = EventEmitter.prototype;
    Clock.prototype.constructor = Clock;
    Clock.uber = EventEmitter.prototype;

    var timer = new Clock();

    timer.getTime.on("time", function() {
        console.log(new Date());
    });
```

Comment: The events are emitted *on* `self`, i.e. the instance, not on the `timer.getTime` member function! They are emitted *by* the interval callback inside the `getTime` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I could achieve it:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function Time(){

}

function Clock() {
}

Time.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
Time.prototype.constructor = Time;
Time.uber = EventEmitter.prototype;

Clock.prototype.getTime = function() {
    var time  = new Time();
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function() {
        time.emit('time');
    }, 1000);
    return time;
};

var timer = new Clock();
timer.getTime().on("time", function() {
    console.log(new Date());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just like this:

```
timer.on("time", function() {
    console.log(new Date());
});

timer.getTime();
```

Although you're emitting an event from within a method, there is no other relationship between the method and the event. You subscribe to events on the Clock object, and you emit events on the clock object.

Also, this is bad, don't ever do this:

```
Clock.prototype = EventEmitter.prototype;
```

You want to do this rather:

```
Clock.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
```

Comment: If I have an object with multiple member functions which emit their own events; as a programming style, I would prefer to bind a callback for the event emitted by that function on calling the same.

Comment: So you want to define a listener for an event for a specific method? The EventEmitter object is not meant to be used in such a way, so that should answer your question. I do think you're making life more complicated than it needs to be. But in any case, here's some code to push you in the right direction: https://gist.github.com/badsyntax/a8f498a2a0469ffadc39 I don't suggest going this route though, it just shows what might be involved. Rather, just use more specific event names.